# How to fix only 5 zombies spawning when supposed to spawn more than that?

Tags: roblox

I've made a module script containing info about each wave, and every wave has its own differences, like different zombies. I made use of a lot of functions. There is a seperate script that executes the waves/functions. However, when I was testing the spawning, only 5 of them appeared, when I clearly stated it in my module script to spawn 8. [image of module script code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1d5J.png)

Heck, it even spawns [4 sometimes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7TU1.png)

I'm relatively confused about this, I even added a barrier just so that they didnt fall off the map.

Is there any flaws with my code?

Comment: Have you tried, just for test purposes, turnin up the wait timer from 1 to 5?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code, instead please transcribe it here so it is easier for us to read. Also, without seeing what the spawn function does, or where it's being called, it's impossible for us to help you on this. Could you please update your question with code samples?

Comment: @Cataklysim yup, but the amount of zombies before i changed it are the same. I've also tried it with 3 and it works pretty well since there's 6 instead of 5 or 4

Comment: Regarding formatted text vs images of text: This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is really important.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
local trollanoidstospawn = 8

repeat
    wait(1)
    trollanoidsummon()
    trollanoidstospawn = trollanoidstospawn-1
until trollanoidstospawn == 0
```